# INotifyPropertyChanged is Null

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, binding, inotifypropertychanged

INotifyPropertyChanged is always null in the follwing snippet

**xaml:**

```
<TextBlock
    Name="tbkContent"
    Text="{Binding Path= value,Mode=TwoWay}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap"
    FontSize="22"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    TextAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="White"
    Height="100"
    Width="400" />
```

**CS:**

```cs
// ...
TextContent content = new TextContent();
// ...

public class TextContent:INotifyPropertyChanged
{      

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;       
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    private string _value;
    public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("value");
        }
    }

}

// ...
private void BindingImages(int ImgId)
{
    switch (ImgId)
    {
        case 1:
            content.value = "binding1";
            break;
        case 2:
            content.value = "binding2";
            break;
        case 3:
            content.value = "binding3";
            break;
        default:
            content.value = "binding4";
            _incrID = 0;
            break;
        }
        DoTransitions(ImgBg);
    }
```

**The TextblockValue is never assigned. this is always null**

```cs
if (PropertyChanged != null) // <-----null here
{

}
```

**Textblock's text is not updating appropriately..**

**Finally, I got on my own, The below has done the trick**

switch (ImgId)
            {

```
            case 1:
                _textcontent = new TextContent();
                _textcontent.content = "binding1";
                tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;

                break;
            case 2:
                _textcontent = new TextContent();
                _textcontent.content = "binding2";
                tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;
                break;
            case 3:
                _textcontent = new TextContent();
                _textcontent.content = "binding3";
                tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;
                break;
            default:
                _textcontent = new TextContent();
                _textcontent.content = "binding4";
                tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;
                _incrID = 1;
                break;
        }
```

I missed Setting the datacontext property.. Thank you all

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The number of brackets doesn't match, the code indentation is wrong and other parts of your post is missing formatting. I'd be happy to edit for you if you'd bother to post proper code, with proper use of brackets.

Comment: @Jon-- The problem is the value is not binding..

Comment: Where did you set the datacontext?

Comment: Do not use `value` as property name. `value` is a C# keyword...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967915/c-wpf-mvvm-and-inotifypropertychanged?rq=1

Comment: @Tonio - I have replaced the value with 'Content' but that does not make any difference.

Comment: You are binding a text **block**. You cannot edit text in a textblock. How/where are you causing the update/set of the property?

Comment: i'm assigning the value to the 'value' variable(in switch) of the 'textcontent' class, which should actually  updates the textblock text. ryt? This is the first time i'm implementing the inotifypropertychanged,hence struggling to understand the core..

Comment: Where did you set up the `DataContext`?

Comment: I dont really know where to set up DataContext? Can someone help me with the solution, providing you understand my question..

Comment: I edit your post and add a null check on `PropertyChanged` handler to prevent null ref exception.

Answer (score 0):

**Finally, I got on my own, The below has done the trick**

I missed Setting the datacontext property...

```cs
switch (ImgId)
{
    case 1:
        _textcontent = new TextContent();
        _textcontent.content = "binding1";
        tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;
         break;
    case 2:
        _textcontent = new TextContent();
        _textcontent.content = "binding2";
        tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;
        break;
    case 3:
        _textcontent = new TextContent();
        _textcontent.content = "binding3";
        tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;
        break;
    default:
        _textcontent = new TextContent();
        _textcontent.content = "binding4";
        tbkContent.DataContext = _textcontent;
        _incrID = 1;
        break;
}
```

Thank you all

Comment: Like @ErnodeWeerd say in comments ;)